Memory alignment for heap allocated values
I've been learning about memory alignment and have some doubts.
In this stackoverflow post, there is a comment:

new and malloc, by default, align address to 8 bytes (x86) or 16 bytes
(x64), which is the optimal for most complex data.

However, with the following code, the alignment of the memory alloced by malloc was 8 bytes.
struct A {
    uint64_t num1;
    uint32_t num2;
    uint16_t num3;
};

printf("alignof(A) = %d\n", alignof(A));

A* a = (A *) malloc(sizeof(A));
printf("sizeof(A) = %d\n", sizeof (A));
printf("alignof(a) = %d\n", alignof (a));
printf("alignof(*a) = %d\n", alignof (*a));
printf("Address pointed by a = %d\n", (uint64_t) a);

The above code produced the following output:
alignof(A) = 8
sizeof(A) = 16
alignof(a) = 8
alignof(*a) = 8
Address pointed by a = 1082707680


Note that the memory allocated by malloc ('Address pointed by a') has an alignment of 8 bytes. Why not 16 bytes (as mentioned in the other stackoverflow post linked above)?
The address allocated by malloc is 16-byte aligned (because it's divisible by 16). I ran this program 10-15 times, and I always get addresses that are 16-byte aligned. But the alignof operator returns 8 bytes.
Quoting from malloc's man page:

The malloc(), calloc(), realloc(), and reallocarray() functions return
a pointer to the allocated memory, which is suitably aligned for any
type that fits into the requested size or less.

The documentation has no mention of 8 bytes or 16 bytes... just that it would be suitably aligned.
If I add a 16-byte variable to the struct, now the alignment of memory allocated by malloc is 16 bytes, which makes sense because the alignment of an aggregate type like struct is based on the largest type in the struct. But in a way, it doesn't make sense - malloc only takes size as a parameter. So, how does malloc know that I'm going to interpret this memory as A type.
Overall, I just want to understand how memory allocation works for heap allocations.
Environment: I'm using clang and I ran this program on a Linux arm64 machine.

how does malloc know - it doesn't, it has a default alignment, which depends on the platform, compiler make, version, and so on.

"Note that the memory allocated by malloc ('Address pointed by a') has an alignment of 8 bytes" How do you figure? 1082707680 == 0x4088CEE0 is divisible by 32.

Type 1082707680 into a prime factorization calculator online and examine the exponent on the 2^n factor - that's the degree of alignment you happened to get.  In this case 2^5 x 3 x 5 x 887 x 2543.   Your data got aligned to 2^5 = 32 bytes (which is also aligned to 8 bytes, as well as 16, and 4, and 2)

"Note that the memory allocated by malloc ('Address pointed by a') has an alignment of 8 bytes." None of your tests prove that. You are printing alignment of a pointer and A. BTW, the argument of alignof is required to be a type (at least, by the standard). alignof(a) and alignof(*a) shouldn't even compile: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/expr.alignof#1.sentence-2.

@DanielLangr I wouldn't be surprised if some compilers allow alignof(expression) as an extension, equivalent to alignof(typeof expression)

"So, how does malloc know that I'm going to interpret this memory as A type." It doesn't. C++ is not C, and in C++, you usually shouldn't use malloc. C++ has its own memory allocation functions called operator new. And, since C++17, there is a variant with which you can specify alignment for over-aligned cases; see https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/basic.stc.dynamic.general#2. Before C++17, there was no portable way (I am aware of), typically some external function had to be used such as posix_memalign.

And the alignment requirement is not "take the sum of all sizes" but rather the largest requirement of the types - which can be changed with _Alignas (C++11) or alignas (C++23).

@ABaumstumpf alignas is C++11.

@IgorTandetnik, I didn't check for 32. I saw that it was divisible by 16 and stopped there. Now I understand how to calculate the alignment of memory (from Wyck's comment). Thanks.

@DanielLangr, you're right. A type should be passed to alignof, and not the variable. But this did compile for me and returned some value.

@NightFuryLxD oh yeah, was mixing that up with C.
